# how to link form action with the buttons

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have 3 buttons : `ADD` , `SEARCH` , `IMPORT` and there are three strut forms within the jsp each form performing add,search and import functions. When the add button is clicked only add form should be shown and when search button is clicked only search form should be displayed.All 3 forms should not be shown at once
How to link the buttons to the form actions

Comment: Hide two forms and show only Add form, when user clicks search button then hide the active form and show the search form..

Comment: Hide forms, but it is better to show you code and tell variants that you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use jquery and ajax call to sumbit the form.

Suppose you have three Form A,B,C and intially a form is shown.

then you should have to use jquery show() and hide() function to show and hide the respective forms.

and you should have to use ajax call to submit you action to server.

i can provide you a code example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".showForm").click(function(e) {
    var form_toshow = $(this).attr("data-form-toshow");

    $("#fomr1").hide();
    $("#fomr2").hide();
    $("#fomr3").hide();
    $("#" + form_toshow).show();
  });

  $("#fomr1form").submit(function(e) {

    //make ajax call to sumit data

    return false;
  });
  $("#fomr2form").submit(function(e) {

    //make ajax call to sumit data
    return false;
  });
  $("#fomr3form").submit(function(e) {

    //make ajax call to sumit data
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
#fomr2,
#fomr3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnshowform1" data-form-toshow="fomr1" class="showForm">
  show form 1
</button>
<button id="btnshowform2" data-form-toshow="fomr2" class="showForm">
  show form 2
</button>
<button id="btnshowform3" data-form-toshow="fomr3" class="showForm">
  show form 3
</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="fomr1">
  <form id="form1form">
    form 1

    <input type="text" name="form1text" id="form1text" />
    <br>
    <button id="sumitForm1">submit form1</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="fomr2">
  <form id="form2form">
    form 2

    <input type="text" name="form2text" id="form2text" />
    <br>
    <button id="sumitForm2">submit form2</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="fomr3">
  <form id="form3form">
    form 3

    <input type="text" name="form3text" id="form3text" />
    <br>
    <button id="sumitForm3">submit form3</button>
  </form>
</div>
```